# Как изменить цвет своего сообщения на сайтах, где есть онлайн чат? если нет такой функции в чате

Tags: javascript, css

Как изменить цвет своего сообщения на сайтах, где есть онлайн чат? Если не предусмотрена такая функция. Редактировал CSS файл, но результата не дало.

```
function Chat() {
    var p = this;
    this.started = !0;
    var a = this.div = new Div({
        x: isMobile ? -offWidth / 2 : 700,
        y: isMobile ? 0 : 40,
        width: isMobile ? 700 + offWidth : 300,
        height: isMobile ? maxHeight - mBottomHeight : 850,
        zIndex: isMobile ? 10 : 0,
        color: "#172736",
        toDiv: mainDiv
    }).div
      , h = this.chatDom = new Div({
        top: isMobile ? 130 : 30,
        className: "chat",
        width: isMobile ? 700 + offWidth : 300,
        toDiv: a
    }).div
      , b = this.chatDomClan = new Div({
        top: isMobile ? 130 : 30,
        className: "chat",
        width: isMobile ? 700 + offWidth : 300,
        toDiv: a
    }).div
      , t = this.topLevelDom = new Div({
        top: isMobile ? 130 : 30,
        className: "chat",
        width: isMobile ? 700 + offWidth : 300,
        toDiv: a
    }).div
      , s = this.topActiveDom = new Div({
        top: isMobile ? 130 : 30,
        className: "chat",
        width: isMobile ? 700 + offWidth : 300,
        toDiv: a
    }).div
      , u = new Div({
        top: isMobile ? 70 : 30,
        className: "chat",
        width: isMobile ? 700 + offWidth : 300,
        toDiv: a
    }).div
      , c = new Div({
        top: 130,
        className: "chat",
        width: isMobile ? 700 + offWidth : 300,
        toDiv: a
    }).div;
    isMobile && new Div({
        width: isMobile ? 700 + offWidth : 300,
        height: isMobile ? 70 : 50,
        color: isMobile ? "#bdcadd" : "#192E3E",
        toDiv: a
    }).div;
    try {
        var i = document.createElement("input");
        i.maxLength = 120,
        i.placeholder = "Введите сообщение...",
        i.className = "input",
        a.appendChild(i),
        i.value = localStorage.getItem("input") ? localStorage.getItem("input") : "",
        window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
            localStorage.setItem("input", i.value)
        }
        ,
        null == uid && (uid = "" != i.value ? i.value : 0),
        i.oninput = function(e) {
            var i, t;
            i = p.inputGet(),
            t = !1,
            (t = "" != appealMes && -1 < i.indexOf(appealMes) ? !0 : t) || (appealMes = "")
        }
    } catch (e) {}
    isMobile ? (h.style.height = maxHeight - 325 + "px",
    b.style.height = maxHeight - 325 + "px",
    t.style.height = maxHeight - 325 + "px",
    s.style.height = maxHeight - 325 + "px",
    u.style.height = maxHeight - 250 + "px",
    c.style.height = maxHeight - 240 + "px",
    i.style.width = 590 + offWidth + "px",
    i.style.height = "38px",
    i.style.fontSize = isMobile ? "24px" : "18px",
    i.style.left = "15px",
    i.style.top = maxHeight - 170 + "px",
    g = new Div({
        x: (maxWidth - gameWidth) / -2,
        y: maxHeight - mBottomHeight,
        width: maxWidth,
        height: iphoneX ? mBottomHeight + iPhoneYOff : mBottomHeight,
        color: "#06141f",
        toDiv: a
    })) : (h.style.height = "750px",
    b.style.height = "750px",
    t.style.height = "750px",
    s.style.height = "750px",
    c.style.height = "750px",
    u.style.height = "750px",
    i.style.top = "800px");
    var o = new Button({
        image: "send_message",
        scale: isMobile ? 1.8 : 1,
        x: isMobile ? 628 + offWidth : 250,
        y: isMobile ? maxHeight - 168 : 801,
        setOrigin: 0,
        toDiv: a
    },function() {
        var e = 0;
        if (2 == subChat) {
            if (!idClan || !clanPosition)
                return void addWindAttention("Внимание!", "Вы не состоите в клане!");
            e = idClan
        }
        p.addMes({
            idUser: idUser,
            vip: vip,
            name: userShortName,
            mes: p.inputGet(),
            pic: lastPresent,
            userPic: userPic,
            bold: corona || userKitsBonus.bold,
            clan: e,
            appealLen: appealMes.length
        }, !0, "log" == p.chatActiveUI),
        appealMes = ""
    }
    );
    isMobile && new Button({
        x: 75,
        y: g.y + 40,
        image: "bCloseMobile",
        zIndex: 10,
        scale: .9,
        toDiv: a
    },function() {
        chat.chatVisible(!1)
    }
    );
    var n = "Игроки, занявшие первые 100 мест в<br>еженедельном рейтинге, получат призы золотом!";
    isMobile && (n = "Игроки, занявшие первые 100 мест в еженедельном рейтинге, получат призы золотом!");
    var l = "Самый активный каждые 3 часа получает<br>3 ключа!";
    isMobile && (l = "Самый активный каждые 3 часа получает 3 ключа!");
    var r = new Par({
        x: isMobile ? 10 + offWidth / 2 : 0,
        y: isMobile ? maxHeight - 175 : 855,
        width: isMobile ? gameWidth - 20 : 300,
        fontName: "SegoeBold",
        fontSize: isMobile ? 22 : 12,
        color: "#BBCADD",
        textAlign: "center",
        toDiv: a
    })
      , f = []
      , m = [];
    function e(e, i) {
        var t, s, o = e.x || 0, n = e.y || 0, l = e.scale || 6;
        e.pic && (t = document.createElement("IMG"),
        "png" == e.typePic ? t.src = "assets/" + e.pic : t.src = "assets/svg/" + e.pic,
        t.className = "noselect",
        t.style.position = "absolute",
        t.style.left = o + "px",
        t.style.top = n + "px",
        t.style.width = l + "%",
        t.style.cursor = "pointer",
        a.appendChild(t),
        i && (t.onclick = i)),
        e.mes && ((s = document.createElement("p")).innerHTML = e.mes,
        s.className = "noselect",
        s.style.position = "absolute",
        s.style.left = o + 25 + "px",
        s.style.top = n - 14 + "px",
        s.style.color = "#bccadd",
        s.style.fontFamily = "SegoeBold",
        s.style.cursor = "pointer",
        e.fontSize ? s.style.fontSize = e.fontSize + "px" : isMobile && (s.style.fontSize = "26px"),
        a.appendChild(s),
        i && (s.onclick = i)),
        this.setPos = function(e, i) {
            !e && 0 != e || (t.style.left = e + "px",
            s.style.left = e + 25 + "px"),
            !i && 0 != i || (t.style.top = i + "px",
            s.style.top = i - 14 + "px")
        }
        ,
        this.setActiv = function(e) {
            s.style.color = e ? "#bccadd" : "#364e65"
        }
        ,
        this.setAlpha = function(e) {
            t && (t.style.opacity = e),
            s && (s.style.opacity = e)
        }
        ,
        this.setVisible = function(e) {
            t && (t.style.visibility = e ? "visible" : "hidden"),
            s && (s.style.visibility = e ? "visible" : "hidden")
        }
        ,
        this.hide = function() {
            t && (t.style.display = "none"),
            s && (s.style.display = "none")
        }
    }
    this.chatActiveUI = "chat";
    var d, M = new Button({
        x: isMobile ? 207 + offWidth / 2 : 235,
        y: isMobile ? 98 : 10,
        label: "ОБЩИЙ",
        fontSize: isMobile ? 24 : 14,
        toDiv: a
    },function() {
        T(1)
    }
    ), y = new Button({
        x: isMobile ? 365 + offWidth / 2 : 180,
        y: isMobile ? 98 : 10,
        label: "КЛАН",
        fontSize: isMobile ? 24 : 14,
        toDiv: a
    },function() {
        T(2)
    }
    ), v = new Button({
        x: 135,
        y: isMobile ? 50 : 10,
        label: "ЛОГ",
        fontSize: isMobile ? 24 : 14,
        toDiv: a
    },function() {
        U("log")
    }
    ), g = 50 + offWidth / 2, x = new e({
        mes: "ОПЫТНЫЕ",
        x: g = isMobile && isOk ? 130 + offWidth / 2 : g,
        y: isMobile ? 73 : 63,
        fontSize: isMobile ? 24 : 14
    },function() {
        S(1)
    }
    ), w = new e({
        mes: "АКТИВНЫЕ",
        x: g + 150,
        y: isMobile ? 73 : 63,
        fontSize: isMobile ? 24 : 14
    },function() {
        S(2)
    }
    ), D = new e({
        mes: "ДРУЗЬЯ",
        x: g + 305,
        y: isMobile ? 73 : 63,
        fontSize: isMobile ? 24 : 14
    },function() {
        S(3)
    }
    );
    isMobile && !isOk && (d = new e({
        mes: "ЛИДЕРБОРД",
        x: g + 420,
        y: isMobile ? 73 : 63,
        fontSize: isMobile ? 24 : 14
    },function() {
        subTop = 5,
        vkConnect.send("VKWebAppShowLeaderBoardBox", {
            user_result: level
        })
    }
    ));
    var C = new Par({
        x: 0,
        y: 15,
        text: "",
        textAlign: "center",
        width: 700 + offWidth,
        fontSize: 30,
        color: "#1f3b50",
        toDiv: a
    });
    isMobile && v.hide();
    var U = this.chatClickUI = function(e, i) {
        r.setText(""),
        p.chatActiveUI = e,
        P(h, !1),
        P(b, !1),
        P(t, !1),
        P(s, !1),
        P(c, !1),
        P(u, !1),
        isMobile && C.setText(""),
        M.setVisible(!1),
        y.setVisible(!1),
        x.setVisible(!1),
        w.setVisible(!1),
        D.setVisible(!1),
        d && d.setVisible(!1),
        "chat" == e && (P(h, !0),
        I(!0),
        isMobile && C.setText("ЧАТ"),
        M.setVisible(!0),
        y.setVisible(!0),
        T(i)),
        "log" == e && (P(u, !0),
        I(!0),
        isMobile ? C.setText("ЧАТ") : (M.setVisible(!0),
        y.setVisible(!0)),
        T(3)),
        "top" == e && (x.setVisible(!0),
        w.setVisible(!0),
        D.setVisible(!0),
        d && d.setVisible(!0),
        I(!1),
        p.topUpdate(),
        S(i),
        isMobile && C.setText("РЕЙТИНГ")),
        menu && (menu.started ? v.setVisible(!1) : v.setVisible(!0)),
        isMobile && v.hide()
    }
    ;
    function T(e) {
        e && (subChat = e),
        P(h, !1),
        P(b, !1),
        P(u, !1),
        M.setTextColor("#364e65"),
        y.setTextColor("#364e65"),
        v.setTextColor("#364e65"),
        1 == subChat && (M.setTextColor("#bccadd"),
        P(h, !0),
        chat.chatActiveUI = "chat"),
        2 == subChat && (y.setTextColor("#bccadd"),
        P(b, !0),
        chat.chatActiveUI = "chat"),
        3 == subChat && (v.setTextColor("#bccadd"),
        P(u, !0),
        chat.chatActiveUI = "log")
    }
    function S(e) {
        e && (subTop = e),
        P(t, !1),
        P(s, !1),
        P(c, !1),
        x.setActiv(!1),
        w.setActiv(!1),
        D.setActiv(!1),
        d && d.setActiv(!1),
        r.setText(""),
        1 == subTop && (x.setActiv(!0),
        P(t, !0),
        r.setText(n)),
        2 == subTop && (w.setActiv(!0),
        P(s, !0),
        r.setText(l)),
        3 == subTop && (D.setActiv(!0),
        I(!1),
        P(c, !0),
        0 < friendsInGameId.length && socket.emit("getOnlineStatus", {
            playersId: friendsInGameId,
            soc: isOk ? 2 : 1
        }))
    }
    function P(e, i) {
        e && (e.style.visibility = i ? "visible" : "hidden")
    }
    function I(e) {
        i.style.visibility = e ? "visible" : "hidden",
        o && o.setVisible(e)
    }
    this.topUpdate = function() {
        function e(o, n) {
            for (var l in n.innerHTML = "",
            o)
                e(Number(l) + 1);
            function e(e) {
                var i = o[l]
                  , t = document.createElement("div");
                t.className = "noselect topBlocks",
                t.style.marginTop = "12px",
                t.style.height = isMobile ? "110px" : "51px",
                i.pic || (i.pic = picDef);
                new Pic({
                    x: isMobile ? 50 : 25,
                    y: 0,
                    borderRadius: isMobile ? 100 : 50,
                    width: isMobile ? 100 : 50,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    src: i.pic,
                    toDiv: t
                });
                new Div({
                    x: isMobile ? 50 : 25,
                    y: 0,
                    width: isMobile ? 96 : 46,
                    height: isMobile ? 96 : 46,
                    borderRadius: isMobile ? 96 : 46,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    border: isMobile ? "3px solid orange" : "2px solid orange",
                    toDiv: t
                }).div.onclick = function() {
                    addUserInfo(i.idUser)
                }
                ;
                var s;
                new Par({
                    x: isMobile ? 7 : -3,
                    y: isMobile ? 35 : 17,
                    fontSize: isMobile ? 25 : 12,
                    width: 30,
                    text: e,
                    textAlign: "center",
                    toDiv: t
                });
                new Par({
                    x: isMobile ? 185 : 85,
                    y: isMobile ? 10 : 0,
                    fontSize: isMobile ? 30 : 16,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    text: i.firstName + " " + i.lastName,
                    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                    toDiv: t
                }).par.onclick = function() {
                    addUserInfo(i.idUser)
                }
                ,
                i.weekLevelElo && (new Pic({
                    x: isMobile ? 187 : 87,
                    y: isMobile ? 55 : 23,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    src: "experienceIcon",
                    toDiv: t
                }).img.onclick = function() {
                    addUserInfo(i.idUser)
                }
                ,
                s = new Par({
                    x: isMobile ? 220 : 115,
                    y: isMobile ? 49 : 23,
                    fontSize: isMobile ? 25 : 16,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    text: i.weekLevelElo,
                    toDiv: t
                })),
                i.activnost && (s = new Par({
                    x: isMobile ? 185 : 85,
                    y: isMobile ? 55 : 23,
                    fontSize: isMobile ? 25 : 16,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    text: i.activnost + " акт.",
                    toDiv: t
                })),
                i.numSub && (s = new Par({
                    x: isMobile ? 185 : 85,
                    y: isMobile ? 55 : 23,
                    fontSize: isMobile ? 25 : 16,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    text: i.numSub + " " + declOfNum(i.numSub, ["игрок", "игрока", "игроков"]),
                    toDiv: t
                })),
                i.price && (new Pic({
                    x: isMobile ? 187 : 87,
                    y: isMobile ? 58 : 25,
                    scale: isMobile ? .7 : .5,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    src: "diamond",
                    toDiv: t
                }),
                s = new Par({
                    x: isMobile ? 232 : 117,
                    y: isMobile ? 55 : 23,
                    fontSize: isMobile ? 25 : 16,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    text: i.price,
                    toDiv: t
                })),
                s && (s.par.onclick = function() {
                    addUserInfo(i.idUser)
                }
                ),
                i.lastPresent && new Pic({
                    x: isMobile ? 120 : 55,
                    y: isMobile ? 65 : 30,
                    scale: isMobile ? .6 : .35,
                    pointerEvents: "none",
                    src: "assets/allgifts/" + i.lastPresent + ".png",
                    toDiv: t
                }),
            }
            new Div({
                x: isMobile ? 50 : 15,
                width: isMobile ? 97 : 47,
                height: isMobile ? 97 : 47,
                borderRadius: isMobile ? 97 : 47,
                cursor: "pointer",
                border: isMobile ? "3px solid orange" : "2px solid orange",
                toDiv: i
            }).div.onclick = function() {
                l(e.uid, e.idUser, e.inApp)
            }
            ,
            new Par({
                x: isMobile ? 185 : 80,
                y: isMobile ? 10 : 0,
                text: e.firstName + " " + e.lastName,
                cursor: "pointer",
                fontSize: isMobile ? 30 : 16,
                whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                toDiv: i
            }).par.onclick = function() {
                l(e.uid, e.idUser, e.inApp)
            }
            e.inApp && !e.online && !includes(goldFriends, e.uid) && goldFriends.length < 10 && new Par({
                x: isMobile ? 385 : 215,
                y: isMobile ? 54 : 28,
                color: "#EFE467",
                text: "+0.2кг",
                fontSize: isMobile ? 22 : 14,
                toDiv: i
            }),
            e.corona && (new Pic({
                x: isMobile ? 107 : 45,
                y: -8,
                scale: isMobile ? .6 : .3,
                pointerEvents: "none",
                src: "corona" + e.corona,
                toDiv: i
            }).img.style.transform = "rotate(35deg)"),
            e.lastPresent && new Pic({
                x: isMobile ? 120 : 50,
                y: isMobile ? 65 : 25,
                scale: isMobile ? .6 : .4,
                pointerEvents: "none",
                src: "assets/allgifts/" + e.lastPresent + ".png",
                toDiv: i
            }),
            c.appendChild(i)
        }
        function l(e, i, t) {
            e < 0 || (t ? (t = !0,
            e == uid && (t = !1),
                    if (t ? socket.emit("newMesSendPrivate", e) : socket.emit("newMesSend", e),
                    banChat)
                        return
                }
                t ? p.addLog({
                    idUser: e.idUser,
                    name: e.name,
                    mes: e.mes,
                    type: "private",
                    tint: e.tint
                }) : p.addMesDom(e),
                i && (p.inputSet(""),
                setTimeout(function() {
                    p.inputFocus(!0)
                }, 100))
            }
    }
    ,
    this.addMesDom = function(i) {
        var e, t = !0, s = i.clan ? b : h;
        if (i.idUser != idUser && s.clientHeight - (s.scrollHeight - s.scrollTop) < -30 && (t = !1),
        !includes(blackListChat, i.idUser) && (i.mes && !i.sysToUid && (i.mes = i.mes.replace(/[<>&]/g, "")),
        !isEmpty(i.mes))) {
            2 < i.mes.length && (e = i.mes) === e.toUpperCase() && (i.mes = i.mes.toLowerCase()),
            i.idUser == idUser || i.clan || (i.mes = containsMat(i.mes));
            var o, n, l, a = isMobile ? 60 : 45, c = document.createElement("div");
            if (i.pic && 0 < i.pic && i.pic <= allPresents ? o = new Pic({
                x: (isMobile,
                5),
                y: isMobile ? 6 : 1,
                src: "assets/allgifts/" + i.pic + ".png",
                cursor: "pointer",
                scale: isMobile ? .38 : .25,
                toDiv: c
            }) : i.idUser < 0 && (l = "board_mini_white",
            -2 == i.tint && (l = "board_mini_orange"),
            -3 == i.tint && (l = "board_mini_purpur"),
            -4 == i.tint && (l = "board_mini_gray"),
            i.userPic = l),
            i.userPic && (n = new Pic({
                x: isMobile ? 43 : 30,
                y: isMobile ? 6 : 1,
                width: isMobile ? 30 : 20,
                src: i.userPic,
                cursor: "pointer",
                borderRadius: 20,
                toDiv: c
            })),
            i.appealLen && 0 < i.appealLen && i.appealLen < 70) {
                var r = '<span style="color:#B47FFC">' + i.mes.substring(0, i.appealLen) + "</span>" + i.mes.substring(i.appealLen, i.mes.length);
                try {
                    -1 < r.indexOf(userShortName) && (r = r.replace(new RegExp("(" + userShortName + ")","g"), '<span style="color:#8733FA">$1</span>'))
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
                i.mes = r
            }
            a = i.tint < 0 ? new Par({
                textIndent: a,
                position: "static",
                color: colorChatSys[-1 * i.tint - 1],
                text: i.name + ": " + i.mes,
                toDiv: c
            }) : i.bold ? new Par({
                textIndent: a,
                position: "static",
                color: colorChatTint[i.tint],
                text: '<span class="fontBold", style="color:#B3CDE1; cursor:pointer">' + i.name + ': </span><span class="fontBold">' + i.mes + "</span>",
                toDiv: c
            }) : new Par({
                textIndent: a,
                position: "static",
                color: colorChatTint[i.tint],
                text: '<span class="fontBold", style="color:#B3CDE1; cursor:pointer">' + i.name + ': </span><span class="fontNormal">' + i.mes + "</span>",
                toDiv: c
            }),
            -1 == i.idUser ? a.setClassName("messageChat messageChatSystem noselect") : a.setClassName("messageChat noselect noLightingTap"),
            i.vip && (a.par.style.textDecoration = "UnderLine"),
            isMobile && (a.par.style.marginLeft = "20px",
            a.par.style.fontSize = "32px"),
            a.par.onclick = function(e) {
                if (!e || !e.target || !e.target.style || "pointer" != e.target.style.cursor)
                    return;
                if (e.target.classList && "sysUserName" == e.target.classList[0])
                    return socket.emit("getUserInfo", {
                        idUser: i.sysToUid || i.idUser,
                        isFriend: !1
                    }),
                if (i.idUser < 0 && !i.sysToUid)
                    return;
                p.inputFocus(1);
                e = p.inputGet();
                if (-1 < e.indexOf(i.name))
                    return;
                appealMes = i.name + ", " + appealMes,
                p.inputSet(i.name + ", " + e)
            }
            ,
            o && (o.img.onclick = d),
            n && (n.img.onclick = d),
            s.appendChild(c),
            50 < s.childElementCount && s.hasChildNodes() && s.removeChild(s.childNodes[0]),
            t && (s.scrollTop = s.scrollHeight)
        }
        function d(e) {
            e && e.target && e.target.style && "pointer" == e.target.style.cursor && (i.idUser < 0 && !i.sysToUid || (socket.emit("getUserInfo", {
                idUser: i.sysToUid || i.idUser,
                isFriend: !1
    }
    ,
    this.clearMes = function() {
        h.innerHTML = ""
    }
    ,
    this.clearMesClan = function() {
        b.innerHTML = ""
    }
    ,
    this.addLog = function(e) {
        var i, t, s, o, n, l, a, c, r, d, p, h = "";
        "log" == e.type && (i = "w" == e.color ? "Б" : "Ч",
        t = e.from.toUpperCase(),
        s = e.to.toUpperCase(),
        p = e.captured,
        o = nameFigRus[e.piece],
        n = e.check ? "ШАХ" : "",
        l = e.checkmate ? "МАТ" : "",
        a = Math.ceil((f.length + 1) / 2),
        c = "Б" == i ? a + " - " : "",
        r = isMobile ? 34 : 22,
        d = isMobile ? 14 : 9,
        e.textIndent = "Б" == i ? 0 : 100 <= a ? r + 2 * d : 10 <= a ? r + d : r,
        h = "O-O-O" == e.san || "O-O" == e.san ? c + i + ": рокировка " + e.san + " " + n + " " + l : c + i + ": " + o + " " + t + "-" + s + " " + n + " " + l,
        p && (game.addCapturedFig("w" == e.color ? "b" : "w", p),
        h += " (x " + nameFigRus[p] + ")"),
        f.push(h)),
        "private" == e.type && (h = e.name + ": " + e.mes,
        m.push(h)),
        "text" == e.type && (h = e.mes),
        e.mes = h,
        (p = e).mes && (p.mes = p.mes.replace(/[<>&]/g, "")),
        isEmpty(p.mes) || (h = !0,
        p.uid != uid && u.clientHeight - (u.scrollHeight - u.scrollTop) < -30 && (h = !1),
        "private" == p.type && p.uid != uid && (p.mes = containsMat(p.mes)),
        (e = document.createElement("p")).className = "messageChat noselect noLightingTap",
        e.style.color = colorChatTint[p.tint],
        p.textIndent && (e.style.textIndent = p.textIndent + "px"),
        isMobile && (e.style.marginLeft = "20px",
        e.style.fontSize = "24px"),
        p = document.createTextNode(p.mes),
        e.appendChild(p),
        u.appendChild(e),
        300 < u.childElementCount && u.hasChildNodes() && u.removeChild(u.childNodes[0]),
        h && (u.scrollTop = u.scrollHeight))
    }
    ,
    this.clearLog = function() {
        game && game.clearCapturedFig(),
        f = [],
        m = [],
        u.innerHTML = ""
    }
    ,
    this.chatVisible = function(e, i) {
        if (isMobile)
            if (e) {
                if ("block" == a.style.display && a.style.opacity)
                    return;
                a.style.display = "block",
                a.style.opacity = 0,
                h.scrollTop = h.scrollHeight,
                b.scrollTop = b.scrollHeight,
                u.scrollTop = u.scrollHeight,
                $(a).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 200, "linear", function() {})
            } else
                i ? (a.style.opacity = 0,
                a.style.display = "none") : (a.style.opacity = 1,
                $(a).animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 200, "linear", function() {
                    a.style.display = "none"
                }));
        else
            e ? (a.style.display = "block",
            h.scrollTop = h.scrollHeight,
            b.scrollTop = b.scrollHeight,
            u.scrollTop = u.scrollHeight) : a.style.display = "none"
    }
    ,
    p.chatVisible(!1, !0),
    this.isChatVisible = function() {
        return "block" == a.style.display
    }
    ,
    this.inputFocus = function(e) {
        i && (e ? i.focus() : i.blur())
    }
    ,
    this.inputGet = function() {
        if (i)
            return i.value
    }
    ,
    this.inputSet = function(e) {
        i && (i.value = e)
    }
    ,
    this.isInputFocus = function() {
        return !!i && $(i).is(":focus")
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ты хочешь, чтобы твои изменения видели все собеседники?

Comment: @Grundy Да, я хочу, чтобы мои изменения видели все собеседники.

Comment: если чат этого не поддерживает - то никак.

Comment: @Grundy Но в чате есть несколько пользователей, которые уже поменяли. Но они не говорят, как сделать)) Вот я решил тут спросить))

Comment: @Grundy ещё эти же люди могут отправлять фотки, тогда как такой функции у чата не предусмотрено))

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ у каждого чата могут быть свои недокументированные возможности. Локальные изменения никак не затрагивают других пользователей. Скорее дело либо в каких-то настройках, либо в особой форме сообщения.

Comment: В любом случае, не зная о каком чате речь, при отсутствии документации - ответить на вопрос невозможно.

Comment: @Grundy Чат работает через Socket.io. А так этот чат находится в Вк играх (Шахматы онлайн). А как посмотреть документации?

Comment: В идеале нужны исходники чата, либо узнать какая именно библиотека использовалась. `Socket.io` отвечает просто за отправку сообщений, и не имеет никакого отношения к тому, как сообщения будут отображаться.

Comment: @Grundy добавил исходник чата, если будет возможность посмотри пожалуйста

Comment: Не уверен, каким образом это делают другие пользователи, однако, можно переопределить метод `addMes` и заменить в отправляемом обращении настройки: цвет текста (номер из массива), имя, картинку рядом с аватаркой

Comment: Обычно, в онлайн чатах (в том числе в различных играх) проявляются "магические" способности для выделения из другой серой массы тех, кто заплатил, заданатил, купил премиум и тд. Либо в инете нашел интересный плагин/патч (или админ/разраб ему должен денег и сделал исключение). Тут понятно одно...меняя код локально - вы ничего не добьетесь.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, не совсем так. на клиенте есть объект чата, отсылающий сообщение в конкретном формате. Если изменить отсылаемое сообщение перед отправкой - всем придет уже измененное сообщение

Answer (score 0):

При отправке сообщения вызывается метод `.addMes`, в котором первым параметром передается объект сообщения с настройками.

Если в этом объекте изменить поле `tint` - то можно изменить цвет, которым будет подсвечиваться сообщение.

`tint`- это число. Положительное значение соответствует индексу элемента в массиве `colorChatTint`:

```
[
    '#bbbbbb', 
    '#EDA090', 
    '#fcef66', 
    '#b5d4f2', 
    '#7DB4EF', 
    '#a8d4af', 
    '#73C773', 
    '#f7d48f', 
    '#888888'
]
```

Вторым параметром передается флаг, показывающий, что это твое сообщение, таким образом можно менять цвет только твоим сообщениям.